# Conan: Central place to specify options of the complete dependency graph

Tags: dependencies, profile, conan

With conan is there a recommended way to specify all the options for the complete dependency graph of an application in a central place?

Consider having all requirements specified in each internal component conan recipe and the main application recipe that depends on these components. The components themselves specify their own requirements such as other components and third party dependencies.

We would like to have control over what binaries are used in the final application(s) and the options of different dependencies might differ from application to application and version to version.

So it seems to be no solution to put the options in each component itself.

Where do you suggest to put the options?

1. Dedicated application conan profile which contains all the options of every dependency and then include it in the build/host profile (or specify both at the CLI). This approach might has the disadvantage that it won't be easy to match application binaries to the used application profile.
2. Specify all options in the application recipe
3. Create a PkgDeps package that is only used to specify all requirements and options and then use it inside the application
4. Any other way to achieve this?

Conan lockfiles doesn't seem to provide the manual control that might be needed to specify which options should be used for each dpendency. However, the lock files might be relevant later for reproducible builds. But as far as I know it is not recommended to create lock files manually.

Comment: The problem of specifying options in the application recipe is that you cannot easily work with a dependency, build it, develop it, without the consumer application. The recommended approach for defining this is using profiles, and if it is variable, it seems that passing 2 profiles in the command line is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks @drodri we are currently preferring this approach as well. The only issue with it is how to match the binaries to a specific version of the "application conan profile". We have all host/build profiles including this application profile inside a dedicated conan-client-config github repository. Do you suggest that we manually create tags of both the conan-client-config repo and the application repo which should match together? Or is there a conan feature that could help with that?

Comment: The use case I am talking about is about reproducing previous builds of the application. So to easily switch back to previous versions of the application and build with the same options of all the dependencies that were previously used.

Comment: Yes, definitely, if the configuration is evolving, it makes a lot of sense to version it as well. I am not sure it is easy to have a matching version with the application, because they might easily evolve independently, so someone should keep the matching. What will be possible in 2.0 is to make some ``conf`` part of the ``package_id`` systematically, so if you pass a ``user.myconf:version=1.2.3`` as configuration, it will become part of the ``package_id``, so it can be listed later and be used to traceback to the configuration version used to build that binary.

Comment: Is this `user.myconf:version` feature already documented, so that I can refer to it? Will this influence only the `package_id` of the main application or influence every dependency as well (for example in case we use `build missing`)? And, should this configuration be part of the `conan.conf`? I guess passing it via CLI is also possible but might be easy to forget.

Comment: Regarding conan lock files, would this be then obsolete or what will be the main use case for them? Is there a way to get the options that were used from the lock file?

Comment: Lockfiles in 2.0 will no longer store options or any configuration, just the versions and revisions used in the graph

Comment: All the ``user.xxxx`` configuration are not documented, because they are user custom configuration, this was just an example. What there is a way to make it part of the package_id. But this conversation maybe is diverging a bit from the main thread, and it is 2.0, maybe it is better to take it to Github issues (and tag it with 2.0)